# Any (rough) equivalent to iOS NSLinguisticTagger for android?

Tags: android, nlp, stanford-nlp, linguistics

In iOS, you can use the NSLinguisticTagger to do things like part-of-speech tagging, and even lemmatizing a word (like recognizing that "went" is a form of the verb "to go") for several different languages.

Is there anything like this for use with android development, that's available for several different languages, as is the case for iOS? I'm aware of stuff like the Stanford NLP, but it seems to only work with a limited number of languages (English + 5 others), which is not sufficient for my purposes. Plus, I'm not even sure if it could work on android. (but correct me if I'm wrong)

It would need to work without accessing the network, so it must do everything on the device without connecting to a service.

I'm afraid the answer is "no"...but asking anyway just in case, before I spend a huge amount of time trying to develop my own workaround.

Comment: Do you know if the NSLinguisticTagger does it only connected? Usually it takes a lot of memory for such tasks. Take a look at [Polyglot](http://polyglot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), it has a lot of languages if it is OK for you to keep connected to a service.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that NSLinguisticTagger does it all natively on the device, without the need to connect to anything - it's baked into CoreFoundation since iOS 5. Someone please correct me if that's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any java-based nlp toolkits in android applications. Here is a list of popular ones with a simple description :

[Stanford CoreNLP](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/)

I don't know exactly how many you mean by several but if you ever want to make a toolkit you can train coreNLP with a corpus.

[Apache OpenNLP](http://opennlp.apache.org)

[Apache Lucene and Solr](http://lucene.apache.org)

Apache's toolkits and analyzers do support more languages and you can also train models with openNLP as well.
You can see a list of languages supported here :
[Languages supported by Solr](http://www.solr-start.com/info/analyzers/).

[GATE](https://gate.ac.uk/download/)